# Save edited cell/s from JTable to database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdbc, jtable

Newbie to JTable. Just got in today.
So I am able to populate my data from database into a JTable.
I am currently stuck in saving the edited cell/s into the database.

I've read many articles. But I haven't found the one

Just a button then save!

Here's my code

```
public class DBEngine {
Connection con = IQConnection.getConnectionMgrInstance().getConnection();
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

public Vector getEmployee() throws Exception{
    Vector<Vector<String>> employeeVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

    try {          

        if (con != null) {

           String query = "SELECT * FROM OGG.TBLSAMPLE";


            try {
                pstm = con.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = pstm.executeQuery();


                while(rs.next()) {
                   Vector<String> employee = new Vector<String>();
                    employee.add(rs.getString(1)); //Empid
                    employee.add(rs.getString(2)); //name
                    employee.add(rs.getString(3)); //position
                    employee.add(rs.getString(4)); //department
                    employeeVector.add(employee);
                }   



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            //lbl_err1.setText("Error");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        //flag = false;
        //lbl_err1.setText("Failed!");
    } finally {

        try{
            if(rs != null){
                rs.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        try{
            if(pstm != null){
                pstm.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }    
    }
   return employeeVector;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is your code for saving into DB?

Comment: None at the moment. Still researching and hoping to find an example of doing it.

Comment: @javaBeginner Are you having trouble with my codes?

Comment: I did not find any codes for inserting,so i had just posted a way to insert into mytable(table name) and in my table there is a field ID.This is the way for inserting.Try this using your own field name and table name.If you find any trouble then you can ask

Comment: @user2510841 I would strongly suggest you to first complete the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) on Swing and JDBC. there you will find out all about buttons and database updates. Read it, try it with your own code and come back here I you are stuck with specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preparedstatement like this way for inserting into DB

```
PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("insert into mytable values(?) ");
pt.setString(1,ID);
int result=pt.executeUpdate();
```

if you want to update then use this way

```
 PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("update mytable set column_name=? ");
    pt.setString(1,ID);
    int result=pt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Or use the SQL `update` statement if you just want to update the existing rows in the database table instead of inserting new ones.

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE SAMPLE SET CLIENT = ?, PARTNER = ?,price = ? WHERE id = "+row);
  
            ps.setString(1, (String) jTblSample.getValueAt(row, 1));
            ps.setInt(2, (Integer) jTblSample.getValueAt(row, 2));
            ps.setInt(3, (Integer) jTblSample.getValueAt(row, 3));
 
            ps.executeUpdate();

Comment: pt.setString(1,ID); <-- is this dynamic. if i edit third row of the column id

Comment: @user2510841 Stackoverflow questions and answers are meant for future uses. Suppose if another user in future has same query like your question then he/she can directly copy my answer.So as per your question,my answer perfectly suits it.Now you have another query regarding UPDATE so post another question.Do not ask all queries on a single one.

Comment: Okay got it, Thanks anyway. In my question, it clearly says SAVE EDITED CELLS, not insert values in a table. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I'm verifying @javaBeginner. Thank you. What if i edited the 3rd row of the column ID, will it update my database?

Comment: @user2510841 could not understand

Comment: Hi @javaBeginner! I can successfully update my table from jTable. But I encountered another problem. If I edited column A. It won't save. If I edit another column B, the edited column A is save but not the column B, if I edit column C, then column B will be saved. So on. Get it? So confusing

Comment: @user2510841 as you have multiple queries so you should post multiple questions.You should not post all the queries in one question.If my answer have helped you then you can accept it or else you can wait for other users to answer